# Rearranging an array to fit into Vue-ApexCharts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

Rearranging an array to fit into Vue-ApexCharts.

I am trying to render a chart from backend data and I've managed to filter this data leaving only three keys I need: created_at, date_end, and name.

```
 Array(10) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​
 0: Object { name: Getter & Setter, created_at: Getter & Setter, date_end: Getter & Setter, … }
​
 created_at: "2023-05-10 16:52:49"
​​
 date_end: "2023-05-15 12:34:00"
​​
 name: "foo"
​
```

But now I need somehow to format this array to fit into ApexCharts series prop format, which is like this:

```
 series: [
        {
          data: [
            {
              x: 'Analysis',
              y: [
                new Date('2019-03-07').getTime(),
                new Date('2019-03-11').getTime()
              ],
              fillColor: '#008FFB'
            },
            {
              x: 'Design',
              y: [
                new Date('2019-03-04').getTime(),
                new Date('2019-03-08').getTime()
              ],
              fillColor: '#00E396'
            },
            {
              x: 'Coding',
              y: [
                new Date('2019-03-07').getTime(),
                new Date('2019-03-10').getTime()
              ],
              fillColor: '#775DD0'
            },
            {
              x: 'Testing',
              y: [
                new Date('2019-03-01').getTime(),
                new Date('2019-03-15').getTime()
              ],
              fillColor: '#FEB019'
            },
            {
              x: 'Deployment',
              y: [
                new Date('2019-03-12').getTime(),
                new Date('2019-03-17').getTime()
              ],
              fillColor: '#FF4560'
            }
          ]
        }
      ],`
```

Where x = obj.name, y = [ obj.created_at, obj.date_end ]

So the result would be something like:

```
series: [
        {
          data: [
            {
              x: obj.name,
              y: [
                new Date(obj.created_at).getTime(),
                new Date(obj.date_end).getTime()
              ],
              fillColor: '#008FFB'
            },
```

I understand that there should be some way to do that using array methods, but I just can't figure out how exactly. Or maybe I'm even thinking in the wrong directon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `response` is your array of backend data, you would use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array of objects formatted for use with ApexCharts

```js
const data = response.map(obj => {
  return {
    x: obj.name,
    y: [
      new Date(obj.created_at).getTime(),
      new Date(obj.date_end).getTime()
    ],
    fillColor: getColor(obj.name)
  }
})

function getColor(name) {
  switch(name) {
    case 'Analysis': return '#008FFB';
    case 'Design': return '#00E396';
    case 'Coding': return '#775DD0';
    case 'Testing': return '#FEB019';
    case 'Deployment': return '#FF4560';
    default: return '#000';
  }
}
```